# Checkbox bidimensional array does not working

Tags: arrays, vb.net, checkbox

I want to create a bidimensional array to plot checkboxes in rows and cols. Nevertheless, this line is not working:
CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Location = New Point(40 + 50 * cols_C1, 20 + 25 * (well_rows - 1 - rows_C1))

The checkboxes are not shown in the location defined.

```
Sub Check_Panel()
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Clear()
    Dim CheckB_Well(,)
    Dim rows_C1 As Integer
    Dim cols_C1 As Integer

    If Opt6.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 6
        well_rows = 2
        well_cols = 3
    ElseIf Opt12.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 12
        well_rows = 3
        well_cols = 4
    ElseIf Opt24.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 24
        well_rows = 4
        well_cols = 6
    End If

    ReDim CheckB_Well(well_rows - 1, well_cols - 1)

    For rows_C1 = 0 To well_rows - 1
        For cols_C1 = 0 To well_cols - 1
            CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1) = New CheckBox
            CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Name = "Well" + Str(rows_C1) + ";" + Str(cols_C1)
            CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Text = Str(rows_C1) + ";" + Str(cols_C1)
            CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Visible = True
            If rows_C1 Mod 2 = 0 Then
                CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Location = New Point(40 + 50 * cols_C1, 20 + 25 * (well_rows - 1 - rows_C1))
            Else
                CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).Location = New Point(40 + 50 * (well_cols - 1 - cols_C1), 20 + 25 * (well_rows - 1 - rows_C1))
            End If
            Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1))
        Next cols_C1
    Next rows_C1
End Sub
```

Comment: There's no reason to have to set the `Location` of the controls. Use a `TableLayoutPanel` as a container. You simply set up the appropriate number of rows and columns and then `Add` your `CheckBoxes` to its `Controls` collection. It will layout the child controls automatically, based on your configuration.

Comment: Or a FlowLayoutPanel if you just need your Controls aligned as you add or remove them to the Container (btw, to remove a Control from the collection of Controls,  use `[Container].Controls.Remove(control)` only if you're already handling a List or Array of Controls built at run-time and you're adding these existing Controls to the Container, otherwise use `control.Dispose()`). Dispose of the Control in that collection when the Form closes.

Comment: The same in relation to your `Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Clear()`: use a backwards `For` loop (from `Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Count - 1` to `0`) and dispose of the Control at the current index in the loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to set `AutoSize` to True:

```
CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1) = New CheckBox
CheckB_Well(rows_C1, cols_C1).AutoSize = True
```

Because it was drawing from left to right on even rows, the extra space from the default size was covering up the CheckBoxes to the right.

Side Note: What is the point of creating the 2D array `Dim CheckB_Well(,)`?  It's a local variable, so it's not necessary:

```
Sub Check_Panel()
    Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Clear()

    If Opt6.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 6
        well_rows = 2
        well_cols = 3
    ElseIf Opt12.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 12
        well_rows = 3
        well_cols = 4
    ElseIf Opt24.Checked = True Then
        well_number = 24
        well_rows = 4
        well_cols = 6
    End If

    For rows_C1 As Integer = 0 To well_rows - 1
        Dim Y As Integer = 20 + 25 * (well_rows - 1 - rows_C1)
        For cols_C1 As Integer = 0 To well_cols - 1
            Dim CB As New CheckBox
            CB.AutoSize = True
            CB.Name = "Well" + Str(rows_C1) + ";" + Str(cols_C1)
            CB.Text = Str(rows_C1) + ";" + Str(cols_C1)
            If rows_C1 Mod 2 = 0 Then
                CB.Location = New Point(40 + 50 * cols_C1, Y)
            Else
                CB.Location = New Point(40 + 50 * (well_cols - 1 - cols_C1), Y)
            End If
            Me.GroupBox3.Controls.Add(CB)
        Next cols_C1
    Next rows_C1
End Sub
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: I'm very thankful for your answer. It was very useful.

Comment: If that solved your problem, hit that Accept button.  If it didn't solve your problem, let us know what is still not working...

Comment: About the Dim CheckB_Well(,) array, I want to use the array in an additional button. In the checkbox positions that are selected, I am going to perform another operation. Actually, I don't know if it is necessary. I used to program in VB6, and arrays are really different in VB.net.

Comment: CONTROL ARRAYS no longer exist, but regular arrays are the same.  If you want to use that array in a different button then declare it at FORM LEVEL so it is accessible.  Right now it is simply a LOCAL variable that goes away once that method is complete.

Comment: Make sure you removed the local declaration, otherwise it will "hide" the form level variable. If you already did,  I'll need more details/code to help you figure it out.